# Format author's name with stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I would like to format a string with authors' names.

`Daenerys Targaryen` to `TARGARYEN, D.`

`George R. R. Martin` to `MARTIN, G. G. R.`

`Luís Inácio Lula da Silva` to `SILVA, L. I. L. da`

The pattern is
`LAST, 1st. 2nd. 3rd. ...`.

It would be awesome if it's possible to format multiple names in one string, like

`Daenerys Targaryen, Luís Inácio Lula da Silva` to `TARGARYEN, D.; SILVA, L. I. L. da`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution using `gsub()` with capture groups, and `"\\U...\\E"` flags to  capitalize last names.

```
library(magrittr)

x <- c("Daenerys Targaryen, George R. R. Martin, Luís Inácio Lula da Silva")

x %>%
  strsplit(", ") %>%
  unlist() %>% 
  gsub("(.*?) (\\w+$)", "\\U\\2\\E, \\1", ., perl = TRUE) %>%
  gsub(" ([A-Z])\\w*\\.?", " \\1.", .) %>%
  paste(collapse = "; ")

# [1] "TARGARYEN, D.; MARTIN, G. R. R.; SILVA, L. I. L. da"
```

Comment: Can I use it with mutate for a dataframe with a `names` variable?

Comment: Sure, either drop in as-is or wrap it in a function. Would the `names` column have just one name per row? If so, remove the `strsplit()`, `unlist()`, and `paste()` steps.

Comment: Could you do it with `x <- data.frame(
  names = c("Daenerys Targaryen, George R. R. Martin, Luís Inácio Lula da Silva",
            "João Silva, Bruno Mioto",
            "Stack Overflow")
)` ?

Comment: Yes, the above code should work fine for that, depending on the what you want the output to look like. If it doesn’t work for your use case, please post as a new question with relevant example dataframe and desired result.

Comment: Done (with answer): https://stackoverflow.com/a/74520869/15611828

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function coded in base R that processes a strings and outputs the expected result.

```r
fun <- function(x) {
  y <- strsplit(x, " ")
  sapply(y, \(s) {
    if(any(nchar(s) == 0L))
      s <- s[nchar(s) > 0L]
    if(all(nchar(s))) {
      n <- length(s)
      out <- character(n)
      out[1L] <- toupper(s[n])
      if(n > 1L)
        out[1L] <- paste0(out[1L], ",")
      first <- substr(s[seq.int(n)[-n]], 1L, 1L)
      i <- first == toupper(first)
      out[-1L][i] <- paste0(first[i], ".")
      out[-1L][!i] <- s[!i]
      paste(out, collapse = " ")
    } else ""
  })
}

x <- c("Daenerys Targaryen",
       "George R. R. Martin",
       "Luís Inácio Lula da Silva")

fun(x)
#> [1] "TARGARYEN, D."      "MARTIN, G. R. R."   "SILVA, L. I. L. da"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

To process a string with several names and output one string, do it in two steps.

```r
y <- c("Daenerys Targaryen, Luís Inácio Lula da Silva")
ll <- lapply(strsplit(y, ", "), fun)
do.call(\(x) paste(x, collapse = "; "), ll)
#> [1] "TARGARYEN, D.; SILVA, L. I. L. da"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>